# ¿Es posible instalar Microsoft SQL Server 2017 en macbook pro con chip M1?

Tags: sql-server, docker, debian, docker-compose

Necesito iniciar una imagen en docker utilizando Microsoft SQL Server 2017 y Debian 7 en una macbook pro con chip m1, ¿Es posible?.

Comment: Creo que en teoría es posible y para eso se utiliza Docker. Sin embargo, no estoy familiarizado con eso. La pregunta más importante es ¿Lo has intentado? De ser así ¿Has tenido problemas? ¿Cuáles son?

Comment: Sí, lo he intentado, pero se genera un problema que no logro identificar. He revisado algunos blogs para encontrar una posible respuesta y al parecer es la arquitectura ARM del computador. Probé con parallels, pero la máquina virtual no permite virtualización anidada (hyper-v) y me recomendaron usar UTM, pero no funciona muy bien. Y por esa razón pregunté, quizás alguien lo hizo. @LuisCazares

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

No te va a funcionar. Lo que sí puedes hacer es crear un contenedor Azure SQL Edge que es muy parecido a una instancia SQL Server excepto que no tiene Full-Text Search y otras funcionalidades.

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=1" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -e "MSSQL_USER=username" -p 1433:1433 -d --name=sql mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```